# (Hackerrank) Ruby - Enumerable - group_by if condition problem

Tags: ruby

I just try to solve this problem. (https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/ruby-enumerable-group-by/problem?isFullScreen=true&h_r=next-challenge&h_v=zen)

My solution is works at ruby mine but at the hackerrank first if condition does not work.

```
def group_by_marks(marks, pass_marks)
  all_students = Hash.new
  failed = Array.new
  passed = Array.new

  marks.each do |student|

    if student[1] < pass_marks
      failed.push(student)
    elsif student[1] > pass_marks
      passed.push(student)
    end

  end
  all_students["Failed"] = failed
  all_students["Passed"] = passed
  puts all_students
end
```

Comment: I think your function is supposed to return a hash (not print it) so instead of `puts all students` just `return all_students` - though I tried that on `hacker rank` and it doesn't seem to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem statement contains this `If a particular key is empty, don't return that key`.

Also, you need to remove puts as you need to return it, `all_students` is the same as `return all_students` cause ruby returns the last line automatically.

So you need to update the last 3 lines with the following.

```
  all_students["Failed"] = failed if failed.any?
  all_students["Passed"] = passed if passed.any?
  all_students
```

Comment: thank you for your advices, Ruby was little confusing if you used C and Java long time :D